# Setting width of an element is adding 5%

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to set the relative width of an element using jQuery's width function, but it keeps adding 5% to whatever value I enter.

For example doing:

`$('.class').width('10%')` sets the width to 15%.

Using `$('.class').css('width', '10%')` works properly, so I'm using that for now.

Comment: Can you [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem? [I can't reproduce it.](https://jsfiddle.net/kL0o6q9w/)

Comment: @showdev I was on jquery 1.11.1. jsfiddle doesn't have an option to go that far back.

Comment: @showdev Also, it looks like .width() adds the padding to the total width, but with old versions of jquery, it added pixels as percentages, so my `padding-right: 5px;` caused it to add 5%. Weird.

Comment: You can add older versions of jQuery manually from a [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) to the "External Resources". [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/kL0o6q9w/6/).

Comment: @showdev see here: https://jsfiddle.net/kL0o6q9w/10/ Your code to show the width in the box gets the width without padding so I removed it. It's easiest to look at the style of the element.

Comment: I see what you mean. I notice that "jQuery versions before 1.8 were not fully trained in the ways of the border-box". One suggestion is to "use .css("width") instead of .width() to make it clear you want to get or set the actual width of the element as specified by the CSS." That helps explain why your code works with `css()` vs `width()`. See [jQuery 1.8 box-sizing](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery `.width()` method sets the width of the content of an element, not including `border` or `padding`, you probably need `.outerWidth()` method which includes `border` and `padding` as well.

**edit**
You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to force `border` and `padding` to be included when using `.width()` to get the computed width, but according to the jQuery website:

> Note that `.width("value")` sets the content width of the box regardless of the value of the CSS `box-sizing` property.

See the official API docs of [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do you know if  `.css('width', '10%')` is equivalent to `.outerWidth('10%')`

Comment: `.css('width', '10%')` works as `.width('10%')`, not `.outerWidth('10%')`.

Comment: I copied showdev's fiddle (thanks showdev!) and added some CSS to better match my use case. It looks like `.width()` always adds padding to the width you define, even with `box-sizing: border-box;`, but `.css('width')` and `.outerWidth()` don't. https://jsfiddle.net/kL0o6q9w/4/